# Cannot delete entity with broken id from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I managed to create an entity in the datastore with the following key: 'mydomainname.se-w3wp--ap-mydomainname.se--v-v2.0--l-webengine4.dll--a-%2F.pipeiisipm9d20c68a-5b24-4161-aa53-a8dd9e44f002--h-C%3Ainetpubempapppoolssmydomainname.semydomainname.se.config--w---m-0--t-20'

It shows up when I list the entities in my application, but I cant find it in the datastore viewer so I can't delete it. Any suggestions on how to get rid of it?

I'm using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if you're using python or java.

With python you can use the [Remote API shell](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Running_Remote_Shell) to query your entity and delete it.

Java's got a remote API as well, but you'll have to write a bit more code to create the client that will run your query and delete the entity.

Comment: I updated the question with language, thanks I guess I missed that. I will try the remote API.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I remoted in, fetched all the models that were wrong and deleted them in a loop. painless and effective. Thanks.